# Sorting by keypath in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my application, I have a Realm model called Trip which stores information about limousine trips. Each trip has a number of Location models associated with it. I'd like to sort my Trips by the `arriveAt` value on the first Location of a trip. Essentially I want:

```
let realm = Realm()
let trips = realm.objects(Trip).filter("closed = false").sorted("locations[0].arriveAt")
// Results with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid sort property', reason: 'Cannot sort on 'locations[0].arriveAt': sorting on key paths is not supported.'
```

Is this possible with Realm without converting my result object to an array?

---

**Edit:**

I also am looking to group my results by the date from `locations[0].arriveAt`, so in a Table view the sections are each day and trips underneath each header by the time.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message says, Realm-native sorting by key path is not yet supported, but adding that feature is already being tracked by https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277.

As for grouping (since grouping is essentially the same as sorting), you'll also have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

As [segiddins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663947/526895) said in his comment as well as the Realm error, this isn't a feature that Realm currently supports.

To support the sorting, I added a `startedAt` property to my `Trip` model which mirrors `trip.locations[0].arriveAt` and sorted by that instead.